# Was the area outside of Chester's Mill destroyed or not?

Tags: under-the-dome

In the TV series [Under The Dome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Under_the_Dome_%28TV_series%29), Episode 11 "Speak of the Devil,"  the four kids go out to the edge of the Dome where they have a vision of Big Jim Rennie bleeding.

The scene is shot at the road near Julia Shumway's house, where the dome crossed an intersection, seemingly in the middle of the town.  In earlier episodes, this same scene is where other people have 'appeared,' and there seems to be significant foreshadowing going on.

My problem with this scene, however, is that the town outside of the dome seems to be unchanged.  Early on, of course, this makes sense - because the dome did come down right in the middle of the town.

But, in episode 5 (Blue on Blue), a large bomb was dropped on the dome that seemed to obliterate everything on the outside.  Not having read the book, I'm wondering, is there an explanation for this discrepancy?  Is the dome projecting a nicer outside, or was the bomb just not that big - or, was this just a glaring continuity problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that the destruction caused by the bomb would be limited to one side of the dome

A large explosion relies on the overpressure wave for a lot of its destructive power and the dome would have prevented the wave from propagating in one direction

Comment: This assumption is confirmed in the final episode of season one (E13 - Curtains). In one scene you can clearly see that only the area on one side of the dome is destroyed while the rest looks unaffected.